Pythonからgmailを使ってメール送信する方法の最新版を教えてください。
3年ほど前に問題なく稼働していた以下のようなPythonコードが現在使えなくなってしまいました。（PythonからGmailを使ってメール送信するものです）
調べたところ、Google側のセキュリティの設定が変更となったようです。これまで「安全性の低いアプリのアクセス」という設定があり、これを有効にすることで、メールアドレスとパスワードをハードコーディングしてGmailを使ったメール送信を行っていたのですが、これが使えなくなってしまいました。
そこで、新たな方法がないかいろいろと確認してみたのですが、以下のコードのようなお手軽な方法での送信について情報が得られませんでした。
「安全性の低いアプリのアクセス」の設定が廃止になった後、「アプリパスワード」という設定があったらしいのですが、現時点で私のGoogleアカウントにそのような設定画面が見当たりません。
何か情報をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたらヒントでもいいのでご教示お願いいたします。
▼私のGoogleの設定画面にはアプリパスワードの設定が表示されていません

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def send_email(sender_email, receiver_email, subject, message):
    # GmailのSMTPサーバーとポート番号
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtp_port = 587

    # Gmailアカウントの認証情報
    gmail_user = 'your_email@gmail.com'  # Gmailのメールアドレス
    gmail_password = 'your_password'  # Gmailのパスワード

    # メールの作成
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = receiver_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    # メール本文の追加
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    # SMTPサーバーへの接続とメール送信
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
        server.starttls()  # TLSを使用してセキュアな接続を確立します
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
        print("メールが送信されました。")
    except Exception as e:
        print("メールの送信中にエラーが発生しました:", e)
    finally:
        server.quit()

# メールの送信
sender_email = 'your_email@gmail.com'
receiver_email = 'recipient_email@example.com'
subject = 'テストメール'
message = 'これはテストメールです。'
send_email(sender_email, receiver_email, subject, message)


既存のアプリパスワードが 1 つも無い場合は、https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords こちらにアクセスすると、作成画面に行けるようです。

アプリパスワードは、公式で説明されている通り、セキュリティの中の「Google にログインする方法」→「2 段階認証プロセス」から行けるはずです。

また、既存のアプリパスワードが 1 つも無い場合は、2 段階認証プロセスを有効にした上で、myaccount.google.com/apppasswords にアクセスすると、作成画面に行けるようです。

安全性の低いアプリから OAuth への移行 によると (アプリから利用する場合？)

2024 年秋以降、管理者とユーザーは Gmail、Google カレンダー、Google コンタクトにアクセスする際にサードパーティ製アプリで OAuth を使用する必要があります。


アクセスにパスワードを使用することはできなくなります（アプリ パスワードは例外です）。


安全性の低いアプリとは、Google 以外のアプリのうち、ユーザー名とパスワード（基本認証）を使用して Google アカウントにアクセスするものです。

OAuthを使った Gmail送信は, 以下が参考になるかもです (以下 必要になりそうな部分を抜粋)
Gmail ソリューションを開発する

Gmail API ドキュメント

クイックスタート: Python
Gmail API メールの送信



